# Getting Segmentation Fault in Realloc

Tags: c

Here i want to create dynamically memory.
here i dnt know the output size and i want to print last final output after while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {

    char *sdpCommand = "sdptool browse 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5";

    FILE *fp;
    fp = popen(sdpCommand, "r");

    char *results = 0;
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n");
        return;
    }

    char* buffer = malloc(514);
    while (fgets(buffer, strlen(buffer) - 1, fp) != NULL) {
        realloc(results, strlen(results) + strlen(buffer));
        memcpy(results + strlen(results), buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }
    printf("Output    :::  %s", results);

    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    sleep(1);

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two main issues:

1. `realloc()` **returns** the new address:

   ```
   new_results = realloc(results, ...);
   if (new_results != NULL) {
     results = new_results;
   } else {
     /* handle reallocation failure, `results' is still valid */
   }
   ```
2. `sizeof()` is not the right way to find out the size of `results` and of `buffer`. It would simply return the size of the *pointer*. For `results`, you probably want to keep track of the allocated size yourself. For `buffer`, you're probably looking for `strlen()`.

Once you fix the above, you need to make sure that `results` ends up as a valid NUL-terminated string. This is necessary for the `printf()` to work correctly.

Comment: ... or `NULL` if the allocation failed.

Comment: To elaborate, `sizeof(results)` and `sizeof(buffer)` return the size of the pointers which is actually known at compile time. There is no way in standard C to query for the size of a dynamically allocated block of memory. Hence you having to remember how much you allocated.

Comment: Can u please tell me where i have to do change the thing and my code works fine?

Comment: Your point 1 should mention that it's horrible practice to assign the return value of `realloc` directly back into your pointer variable. You have to first check that it didn't fail...

Comment: @user1089679 You won't learn anything if we do it for you. You need to understand.

Comment: +1 good answer and it makes me happy when somebody fixes an issue like that so quickly. :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan okie sir. i will try .. can u please upload any code Exaple so can i learn from their..

Answer (score 3):

Your code is just blindly forging ahead, seemingly written according to the "it compiles, it must be working" paradigm. I'm sorry if that sounds harsh, it's not a comment about you personally of course.

You need to really *look* at the documentation for the API:s you're trying to use, and analyze whether or not your usage makes sense.

You can't ignore the return value from `realloc()`, how would you get the newly allocated memory? It can't be changing your existing pointer, since you're passing it by value.

The way a dynamic array generally needs to work is to keep track of three things:

- The current array's base address
- The number of elements (bytes, in your case) that the array holds right now
- The number of elements that the array can hold, maximum (before it needs to grow)

When appending *n* new elements, you check if doing so overflows the number of elements, so it becomes larger than the max. That is not allowed, so in that case you need to re-allocate the base array so the new data fits, and (of course) update the array's state accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> realloc(results, sizeof(results) + sizeof(buffer));

This line could be the problem.

1. `realloc()` returns the new address allocated with the specified size, and there's no guarantee that it will be the same address the pointer had before; So, you should always reassign your pointer:

   ptr = realloc( ptr, newSize );
2. `sizeof()` will not return the dynamic allocated size of a pointer. In this case `sizeof(results)` and `sizeof(buffer)` are most probably returning always 8. You might replace with:

   results = realloc(results, ctr * 514);
   *Where ctr is a `short` initialized with 0 before the `while` and counting the number of iterations.*
3. Since buffer is always 514 why don't you reduce the load by redifining it to:

   char buffer[514];

   Best Regards

Comment: Assigning 0 to a pointer is perfectly valid and the standard requires the compiler to assign `NULL` to the pointer in those cases.